# Will a clothes dryer vent pipe get hot enough to ignite Tyvek if they are touching?

Tags: pipe, dryer, vent, heat

It’s a small exterior closet type enclosure. The studs have Tyvek attached then cement board nailed off to that on exterior. The dryer vent pipe goes out of wall but the fin on first elbow hits tyvek as space is small. Thanks.

---

[image]
This is the first elbow from dryer touching Tyvek.

Comment: I doubt it, but tyvek is easy to cut away if you are worried.  A 1/2 inch is more than enough.

Comment: A few photos would really help clarify the situation

Comment: only if your dryer catches fire,

Answer (score 6):

The melting point of Tyvek ® is 135°C and the ignition point is approximately 400°C.

The dryer vent does not exceeds 55°C, otherwise your clothes would be irreparably damaged.

To answer your question, no there is no fire danger from contact.

Comment: Thank you! I’m not concerned about the temp of air exiting vent though. It’s the vent pipe and if it gets enough heat build up during cycle as there is part of vent pipe touching the Tyvek.

Comment: @Gitarzn it would need to be gloving hot (red)

Comment: The pipe can't get any hotter than the air moving through it, which is nowhere hot enough to ignite anything.